# Empty space below coordinator layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

I'm working on a view that need to be scrolled using coordinator layout and inside it should have recyclerview.
i've tried several answer, but it didn't work at all.
There's still empty space below the recycler view section.

Here's my activity.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.woi.adeisme.MainActivity"
    android:background="#ff0000"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:text="Masa?"
                    android:paddingTop="60dp"
            android:paddingBottom="60dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:background="#0000ff"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_margin = "0dp">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

i've tried :
1. set layout_height = match_parent / wrap content
2. fitsSystemWindow
3. fillPort
and this still not working..

can anybody help me ?

[image: the red one is the empty space]

Comment: Do you have space between each item(One item only show in one screen)? or you have space at bottom of RecycleView?

Comment: share screenshot..

Comment: How is the *Runtime* output looks ? show us.

Comment: @Shasapo , so you are trying to make the toolbar scroll along with recyclerview scrolling behaviour ? and how many items the recyclerview have?

Comment: @Omi done i've posteed the ss

Answer (score 0):

try Linear layout instead of CoordinatorLayout like below this may help

```
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:background="#ff0000"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:text="Masa?"
                android:paddingTop="60dp"
                android:paddingBottom="60dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:background="#0000ff"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:layout_margin = "0dp"/>

    <!-- <include layout="@layout/useless_content"/>-->

</LinearLayout>
```